# Boot Ubuntu ISO image from PXE server

Tags: pxe

I'm trying to boot ubuntu-amd64-desktop from PXE server. I want to install the system afterwards.

Currently, I am using `memdisk` to load and boot the ISO CD image:

```
label server
  menu label Instal ISO
  linux memdisk
  append iso initrd=ubuntu.iso raw
```

When booting the client via PXE, the ISO is loaded correctly.
But during startup, it fails to boot and I am dropped into `initramfs`.

It said it can't access the filesystem.

So what option do I need to get that working?

Comment: Try this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PXEInstallServer

Comment: How much RAM do you have in that machine and what's the size of the ISO image?